# Insert value into TEXTAREA where cursor was

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea and a div with values. When I click on a value I insert it into textarea. I need it to be inserted where my cursor was in textarea. Why do I say WAS? Because when I move it out and click on a value to insert, I assume it looses focus in the text area.

So, my question is, is there a way to "remember" the latest cursor position within textarea and then insert my values at that position?

Perhaps it could be a char number in a string?.. Currently I add it like this:

```
input.val( function( i, val ) { return val + " " + myInsert + " "; } );
```

Also I use jQuery, perhaps I could use it?

Comment: I kinda asked the same question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605401/insert-link-in-contenteditable-element

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've written a cross-browser jQuery plug-in for dealing with the caret/selection in textareas and text inputs called [Rangy inputs](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) (terrible name, I really should think of a better one). A combination of methods from this and the techniques in [Edgar Villegas Alvarado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889127/insert-value-into-textarea-where-cursor-was/5889281#5889281) should do the trick, although in IE, the `focusout` event fires too late and you'll need to use the proprietary `beforedeactivate` event instead:

```
var $textBox = $("#foo");

function saveSelection(){
    $textBox.data("lastSelection", $textBox.getSelection());
}

$textBox.focusout(saveSelection);

$textBox.bind("beforedeactivate", function() {
    saveSelection();
    $textBox.unbind("focusout");
});
```

When inserting text later, the following will insert text at the previous cursor position (or overwrite the previously selected text, if the user had selected any):

```
var selection = $textBox.data("lastSelection");
$textBox.focus();
$textBox.setSelection(selection.start, selection.end);
$textBox.replaceSelectedText("Some new text");
```

See jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rQXrJ/1/

Comment: This is great! However in IE the tag is inserted at the beginning of the string. Works great in FF.

Comment: That's because `focusout` is too late in IE: you need to use `beforedeactivate`. Amending...

Comment: @BSQ: Good work. I assume that's WebKit/Blink-only? Other browsers never implemented the textInput event and your change doesn't work in Firefox (I haven't tested IE but I'd bet it won't work).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do check it out at:
http://jsfiddle.net/J5Z2n/1/

```
Hello there my good friend....
how do you do
```

the jQuery:

```
function insertAt (myField, myValue, startSel, endSel) {
    if (startSel || startSel == '0') {
        var startPos = startSel;

        var endPos = endSel;

        myField.val(myField.val().substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ myField.val().substring(endPos, myField.val().length));

  } 
  else {

      myField.val() += myValue;

  }
}

// calling the function
var targetBox = $('textarea#insert'),
    startSel, 
    endSel;
targetBox.bind('focusout', function() {
    //insertAtCursor(this, 'how do you do');
    startSel = this.selectionStart;
    endSel = this.selectionEnd;
});

    $("#myvalue").click(function() {
        var myValue = $(this).text();
        insertAt(targetBox, myValue, startSel, endSel);

    });
```

The original function was borrowed from this post
http://alexking.org/blog/2003/06/02/inserting-at-the-cursor-using-javascript

That should give you a solid head start I hope. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the caret (the cursor) is somewhere in the text field, it registers in Javascript as an empty selection. That is, the selectionStart and selectionEnd attributes are the same. You can use those attributes to detect the position of the caret.

Comment: I am still not sure how would I insert my value if I know caret position? I am desperate for some examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently selectionStart and selectionEnd are quite useful here. Check this out: 
http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery Caret plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCaret) to get/set the cursor position .
Example usage:

```
var cursorPosition = $("#textbox").caret().start);
```

You could 'store' this position like this:

```
$("#textbox").focusout(function(){
   var cursorPosition = $(this).caret().start);
   $(this).data("lastCursorPos", cursorPosition);
});
```

To retrieve it (on your div click event), do this:

```
var lastCursorPosition = $("#textbox").data("lastCursorPos");
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: That sounds promising, thanks. How would I insert the value into this position?