# Add Tags to Textarea by click on Tags respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this **small Js Module** in which I have a list of Tags:

E.g : Username , Email etc

When I click on **Username** its should type in [USERNAME] automatically in textarea. Which I have tried and working fine.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyfa2/1/)

Now the problem is when I add tag , it always add at the end of the text.

Look at this string: Hi [USERNAME] , this is your ['EMAIL'].

Now if I forgot to select [USERNAME] and I typed : **Hi  , this is your ['EMAIL'].**

So now if I click after Hi and then I choose **Username Tag**, it will add the tag at the End instead of adding it after "Hi"

How can I fix this thing ?

**Here is my Code:**

**JS:**

```
$('.tags').click(function (){
    var currentTag = $(this).attr("id");
    var currentTxt = $('#description').val();

    $('#description').val(currentTxt+currentTag);   
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Tags: <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tags" id="[USERNAME]">USERNAME</a> , <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tags" id="[EMAIL]">EMAIL</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also check my DEMO here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyfa2/1/

**In very simple words:** Type this sentence in textarea:

```
              Hi , this is your Email
```

Now click after Hi and then click on Username Tag.

I want it like this:

```
Hi [USERNAME] , this is your Email.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below function and update me if any!

```
  var $textBox;

 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.tags').click(function (){
        var currentTag = ' ' +$(this).attr("id")+' ';
        var currentTxt = $('#description').val();
       insertText(currentTag);


    });    
        $textBox = $("#description");

        function saveSelection(){
            textBox.data("lastSelection", $textBox.getSelection());
        }

        $textBox.focusout(saveSelection);

        $textBox.bind("beforedeactivate", function() {
            saveSelection();
            $textBox.unbind("focusout");
        });
    });

    function insertText(text) {
        var selection = $textBox.data("lastSelection");
        $textBox.focus();
        $textBox.setSelection(selection.start, selection.end);
        $textBox.replaceSelectedText(text);
    }
```

`demo:`http://jsfiddle.net/rQXrJ/121/

Source & Explanation : [Insert value into TEXTAREA where cursor was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889127/insert-value-into-textarea-where-cursor-was)