# Insert value into last textarea where cursor was

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, textarea, textselection

Basically this question is pretty similar to:

[Insert value into TEXTAREA where cursor was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889127/insert-value-into-textarea-where-cursor-was)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rQXrJ/1/

The thing is, I can't get it to work for multiple textareas.

I've tried multiple combinations of things but still no success:

1)

```
$("#foo-1").click(function () {
    $textBox = $(this);    
    $textBox.focusout(saveSelection);
});

$("#foo-2").click(function () {
    $textBox = $(this);    
    $textBox.focusout(saveSelection);
});
```

2)

```
function changeTextBox(newID) {
    var fullID = "#" + newID;
    $textBox = $(newID);      
    $textBox.focusout(saveSelection);
}
$(".txt").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    changeTextBox(id);         

});
```

Here's my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yneco5ft/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the same class to your textareas and set `$textBox` to that class.
Example : http://jsfiddle.net/rQXrJ/283/

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I knew it was something silly. Thanks a lot!