# Get elements in text selection

Tags: javascript, dom, range

I want to get all of the elements contained in a user selection (as in DOM 2 ranges / MS TextRanges).

```javascript
/** @return {Array.<Element>} */
function getSelectedElements() {

  var elements = [];

  // get elements in the user selection somehow

  return elements;

}
```

I've tried to do this by following Tim Down's excellent [solution to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5614571/886931), and some Moz and MS docs, and some PPK stuff.

The approach is basically:

---

- Define SelectionLikeObject as a DOM Selection or an IE Selection.
- Define RangeLikeObject as a DOM Range or an IE TextRange.
- Let `containerNode` be a Node.
- Let `containerElement` be an Element.
- Let `containedElements` be a NodeList.
- Let `elementRange` be a RangeLikeObject.
- Let `selectedRange` be a RangeLikeObject.
- Let `selectedElements` be an Array of Elements.
- Let `element` be an Element.
- Let `selection` be a SelectionLikeObject.
- Set `selection` from the user's selection.
- Set `selectedElements` to a new Array.
- For each `selectedRange` in `selection`:

  - Set `containerNode` to the common ancestor container of `selectedRange`.
  - Set `containerElement` to the closest Element ancestor to `containerNode`.
  - Set `containedElements` to a list of descendants of `containerElement`.
  - For each `element` in `containedElements`:

    - Set `elementRange` from `element`.
    - If the boundaries of `elementRange` fall within the 
      boundaries of `selectedRange`:

      - Push `element` onto `selectedElements`.

---

The DOM branch looks like this:

```javascript
/** 
    @param {Document} doc
    @return {Array.<Element>} 
*/
getSelectedElements.fromDOM = function (doc) {

  /** @type {Range} */
  var selectedRange;

  /** @type {Array.<Element>} */
  var selectedElements = [];

  /** @type {Node} */
  var containerNode;

  /** @type {Element} */
  var containerElement;

  /** @type {NodeList} */
  var containedElements;

  /** @type {Range} */
  var elementRange;

  /** @type {Element} */
  var element;

  /** @type {Selection} */
  var selection = doc.defaultView.getSelection();

  /** @type {number} */
  var rangeCount = selection.rangeCount;

  /** @type {number} */
  var elementCount;

  /** @type {number} */
  var i;

  // hack for browsers without getRangeAt
  // see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

  if (!selection.getRangeAt) {

    selection.getRangeAt = function (i) {
      /** @type {Range} */
      var range = doc.createRange();
      if (i || !selection.anchorNode) {
        return range;
      }
      range.setStart(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset);
      range.setEnd(selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);
      return range;

    };

    selection.rangeCount = 1;

  }

  elementRange = doc.createRange();

  for (i = 0; i < rangeCount; ++i) {

    selectedRange = selection.getRangeAt(i);

    containerNode = selectedRange.commonAncestorContainer;

    while (containerNode && containerNode.nodeType != 1) {

      containerNode = containerNode.parentNode;

    }

    if (!containerNode) {

      return selectedElements; // something went wrong...

    }

    containerElement = /** @type {Element} */ containerNode;

    containedElements = containerElement.getElementsByTagName('*');

    elementCount = containedElements.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < elementCount; ++i) {

      element = containedElements[i];

      elementRange.selectNodeContents(element);

      if (elementRange.compareBoundaryPoints(selectedRange.END_TO_START, selectedRange) < 1 &&
          elementRange.compareBoundaryPoints(selectedRange.START_TO_END, selectedRange) > -1) {

        selectedElements.push(element);

      }
    }
  }

  elementRange.detach();

  return selectedElements;

};
```

The IE branch looks like this:

```
/** 
    @param {Document} doc
    @return {Array.<Element>} 
*/
getSelectedElements.fromIE = function (doc) {

  // Selection - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd347133(v=vs.85).aspx
  // TextRange - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347140(v=vs.85).aspx
  // ControlRange - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537447(v=vs.85).aspx

  /** @type {TextRange|ControlRange} */
  var ieRange = doc.selection && doc.selection.createRange();

  /** @type {Array.<Element>} */
  var selectedElements = [];

  /** @type {TextRange} */
  var selectedRange;

  /** @type {Element} */
  var containerElement;

  /** @type {NodeList} */
  var containedElements;

  /** @type {TextRange} */
  var elementRange;

  /** @type {Element} */
  var element;

  /** @type {Selection} */
  var selection;

  /** @type {number} */
  var i = -1;


  if (ieRange.text === void 0) {

    return []; // FIXME: It's a ControlRange, give up.

  }

  selectedRange = /** @type {TextRange} */ ieRange;

  containerElement = selectedRange.parentElement();

  containedElements = containerElement.getElementsByTagName('*');

  elementRange = doc.body.createTextRange();

  while ((element = containedElements[++i])) {

      elementRange.moveToElementText(element);

      if (elementRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", selectedRange) > -1 && 
          elementRange.compareEndPoints("EndToStart", selectedRange) < 1) {

        selectedElements.push(element);

      } 
  }

  return /** @type {Array.<Element>} */ selectedElements;

};
```

Now, the issue I want to solve is this: if only part of the text in an element is selected, it appears in the returned array, even though it is only [partly selected](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-Containment).

I'd like to add a parameter that changes the behavior to only include fully-selected elements. I have a feeling the answer lies with compareBoundaryPoints, I just don't understand it well enough to figure it out yet.

Also, the IE code is untested so far, but please let me know if anything looks wrong with it (or the DOM branch).

Comment: You may have difficulty defining "contained". One approach may be to remove all whitespace from the selected text, then get the text content for the elements at the extremes and get their white-space reduced text content and see if it's wholy contained in the selection (either test, match or indexof should do the trick). If it is, the whole element is selected. If not, it isn't.

Comment: @RobG maybe it could be done by checking `anchorOffset` and `focusOffset`? If the entire content of an element is selected, I want to consider it "fully selected," otherwise only "partly selected." In most cases the start and end element will be partly selected. In fact, maybe I could always just treat them as partly selected...

Comment: @RobG: There's no need for that: you can get reasonably precise boundaries for the selection in all major browsers.

Comment: @TimDown I was sort of hoping you would chime in on this. If you have a few minutes later, could you explain how to use compareBoundaryPoints/compareEndPoints to only get elements that fall completely within the selection?

Comment: @TimDown I think I figured it out actually. Thanks anyway, your work on that other question helped me get here.

Comment: I was intending to have a proper look at this but I'm glad to see you've sorted it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting some sleep and reading up on [compareBoundaryPoints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.compareBoundaryPoints) again, I think I have the answer.

```
if (elementRange.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_START, selectedRange) > -1 &&
    elementRange.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, selectedRange) < 1) {
```

This seems to only evaluate to `true` for elements that fall completely within the user selection.