# Setting target = _blank for the browser createlink command

Tags: javascript, browser

The Mozilla browser has a createlink command that Rich Text Editors can call but I don't see a way to specify `target = _blank` to make the link open in a new page.   I tried including target=_blank in the URL, like  this

```
http://www.google.com target=_blank
```

But that keeps the link from working.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This question may have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605401/230167

Comment: @Bryan Lots of good stuff there about range selection that I saved for the future, but didn't see anything on setting target.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it

You can add

```
target="_blank"
```

to the url you pass to createLink but you have to be very careful to get the quotes right.  You have to pass a string parameter, url, to createLink that causes the command to receive something like

```
                      "http://www.google.com"  target="_blank"
```

Another problem I was having is that I was putting the link into an element that had contentEditable="TRUE".    Links don't behave well in these elements.