# URL smalltalk prompt not working with electron

Tags: javascript, electron, prompt

sorry if this is a rookie question, but here it goes. Since electron doesn't support prompts I am trying to use [Smalltalk] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/smalltalk} to trigger one to insert an URL but it is not working, I have tried several options and still not working, here is the code:

```
// Insert Link //

const smalltalk = require('smalltalk');

function run(cmd, ele, value = null) {
    let status = document.execCommand(cmd, true, value);
    if (!status) {
        switch (cmd) {
            case 'insertLink':
                smalltalk.prompt('Enter url')
    .then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('cancel');
    });
                if (value.slice(0, 4) != 'http') {
                    value = 'http://' + value;
                }
                document.execCommand('createLink', false, value);

                // Overrides inherited attribute "contenteditable" from parent
                // which would otherwise prevent anchor tag from being interacted with.
                atag = document.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
                atag.setAttribute("contenteditable", "false");

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you just want *any* prompt: I usually use this one and that works: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-prompt. It properly creates electron browser windows for all prompts.

Comment: Note that the Smalltalk tag is about the programming language Smalltalk, not this JavaScript package.

Comment: @JayK I have removed the Smalltalk tag.  JayK is right.  Smalltalk tag is reserved for Smalltalk language.

Comment: hi @AndreasDolk thanks a mill for your help. Yes, I don't have a preference, I just want any prompt that will allow users to enter an URL. I tried your solution, but I must be doing something wrong because it is not working .

Comment: Not sure what 'not working' means. Your actual call is in a switch/case. Have you tried spawning a dummy prompt dialog from somewhere else in the code - somewhere where you're absolutely sure that it's called?

Comment: hi @AndreasDolk apologies. I am getting the same error: 

uncaught Error: prompt() is and will not be supported.
    at window.prompt (window-setup.ts:279)

I installed electron-prom as per guidelines but I think this is due to my limited js knowledge. I am unsure about where to place the following 2:

prompt([options, parentBrowserWindow]).then(...).catch(...)

and

const smalltalk = require('smalltalk');

and if by placing these 2 in the right place this will work with the code I presented above.

Comment: Ah ok. That's strange, because both libraries do not use the browsers `prompt` method. Smalltalk renders some HTML element and places them like a dialog, electron-prompt spawns new browser windows. It looks like you have to check all your code again, maybe you forgot one call to `prompt()` or `window.prompt()`. Or: you have typescript errors, ts didn't compile because of that and you still use previously compile javascript with the old error. Find and delete your generated `window-setup.js` file and check if it get's created again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end, I got it sorted by working with the 'insert link' functionality in javascript, as per [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605401/insert-link-in-contenteditable-element).
Clearly it was my limited knowledge of what was preventing me from getting this or other solutions to work on electron. It is all sorted now. Thanks again for your help and your time!